# logarithmic Series

Tags: logarithms

I'm aware that by properties of logarithm $$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln (k) = \ln (n!)$$

My question is if $$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln^2 (k) = \ln^2 (n!)?$$

Because when I am verifying the value where $n = 5$, I get different result... maybe Im missing something... is there a formula that defines $$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln^2 (k)\text{ ?}$$

Here's my computation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln^2 (k) = \ln^2 (n!)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 \ln^2 (k) = \ln^2 (5!)$$
$$\ln^2(1)+\ln^2(2)+\ln^2(3)+\ln^2(4)+\ln^2(5) = \ln^2 (120)$$
$$0+0.48045+1.20694+1.92181+2.59029 = 22.92007$$
$6.199494$ is not equal to $22.92007$.

Comment: Why do you expect that $$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n $$ implies $$ S^2=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n^2 $$ ???

Comment: No, you actually have $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k\right)^2=\ln^2 (n!)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^n\ln^2k\ne\ln^2n!$ because

$$\ln^2(xy)=(\ln x+\ln y)^2\ne\ln^2x+\ln^2y.$$